# Ingreso e impresion de datos de un vector

Tags: c++

Tengo este codigo

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int i, Num1;

int main()
{int Columna;
int ValorIngresado;
int FilaA [9],a;

    for (a=0;a<9;a++)
     {
       FilaA[a]=0;
     }

    printf("Digite la columna:\n");
    scanf("%d", &Columna);
   printf("Digite un valor entre 1-9 que desea ingresar en la posicion [%d]: \n\t", Columna);
   scanf("%d", &ValorIngresado);
   FilaA[Columna]=ValorIngresado;
  printf("%d  %d  %d  %d  %d  %d  %d  %d  "), FilaA[0], FilaA[1], FilaA[2], FilaA[3], FilaA[4], FilaA[5], FilaA[6], FilaA[7], FilaA[8];}
```

Donde en resumen, necesito inicializar todos los valores del vector en 0, y al pedir el dato de columna (La casilla del vector) y el valor ingresado, para que ese 0 de la casilla "Columna" cambie a ese dato de "ValorIngresado", pero en la impresion final da algo que no le veo sentido, cambian 4 valores en lugar de solo el que se le ingreso el dato, ¿Que estoy haciendo mal? Quedo atento a las respuestas, gracias de antemano

Comment: C **NO** es C++ y lo mismo al revés. Son lenguajes diferentes con sus propias características. En tu caso el código es C++ por la librería `cstring`.

Answer (score 1):

> necesito inicializar todos los valores del vector en 0

```
int FilaA[9] = {0};
```

Mejor que andar programando un bucle, ¿no?

Por cierto, en C++ (y ya puestos en C99 y posteriores) es legal declarar variables dentro de los bucles:

```
for( int i=0; i<9; i++ )
//   ^^^
```

> y pedir el dato de columna

No hace falta usar variables temporales para recuperar valores del teclado:

```
// Esto...
scanf("%d", &ValorIngresado);
FilaA[Columna]=ValorIngresado;

// ... queda asi mas limpio ...
scanf("%d",&FilaA[Columna]);
```

Aunque, por otro lado, estás programando en C++... así que te recomiendo usar la sintaxis propia de C++:

```
#include <iostream>

std::cout << "Digite la columna:\n";
std::cin >> Columna;
std::cout << Digite un valor entre 1-9 que desea ingresar en la posicion [" << Columna << "]: \n\t";
std::cin >> FilaA[Columna];
```

Y, para rematar la jugada, considera contemplar si los datos introducidos por el usuario son correctos (independientemente de que uses la versión C o la versión C++):

```
#include <limits>

do
{
  std::cout << "Digite la columna:\n";
  std::cin >> Columna 
  if( std::cin.fail() ) // No se ha introducido un numero
  {
    // Descartar lo que haya en el buffer de entrada
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<int>::max());

    // Limpiar los flags de error
    std::cin.clear();
  }
}
while ( Columna < 0 || Columna > 8 );

std::cout << Digite un valor entre 1-9 que desea ingresar en la posicion [" << Columna << "]: \n\t";
std::cin >> FilaA[Columna];
```

> pero en la impresion final da algo que no le veo sentido, cambian 4 valores en lugar de solo el que se le ingreso el dato

```
printf("%d  %d  %d  %d  %d  %d  %d  %d  "), FilaA[0], FilaA[1], FilaA[2], FilaA[3], FilaA[4], FilaA[5], FilaA[6], FilaA[7], FilaA[8];
//                                       ^ AQUI
```

Ese paréntesis finaliza la función `printf`. Como no le pasas ningún parámetro y estás teniendo bastante suerte la función se está limitando a imprimir basura. La solución rápida pasa por desplazar ese paréntesis al final de la línea:

```
printf("%d  %d  %d  %d  %d  %d  %d  %d  ", FilaA[0], FilaA[1], FilaA[2], FilaA[3], FilaA[4], FilaA[5], FilaA[6], FilaA[7], FilaA[8]);
```

Aunque también podrías conseguir un código más manejable y menos propenso a errores si usas bucles:

```
for( int i=0; i<9; i++ )
  printf("%d ",FilaA[i]);
```

Y quedaría incluso mejor si usases la funcionalidad propia de C++:

```
for( int i=0; i<9; i++ )
  std::cout << FilaA[i] << ' ';
```

Answer (score 0):

tu problema es que cerraste la función `printf` antes de poner los datos

```
printf("%d  %d  %d  %d  %d  %d  %d  %d  ", FilaA[0], FilaA[1], FilaA[2], FilaA[3], FilaA[4], FilaA[5], FilaA[6], FilaA[7], FilaA[8]);
```